# Perform diff on RTF and preview changes

Tags: c#, .net, rtf

I am looking to compare two RTF files and provide a way of highlighting the differences. Does anybody know of anyway I can do this? The project is a .net project, however worst case, I'm sure I could implement an unmanaged app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that depends.

If you just want to view the difference between the RTF "code", i.e. the plain textfiles, you could employ a library like [DiffPlex](http://diffplex.codeplex.com/).

If you want some WYSIWYG view, i.e. including formatting, etc., you could actually use Word (via Automation). Much like TortoisSVN ([xdocdiff](http://freemind.s57.xrea.com/xdocdiff/e/index.html)) does it.

Comment: Hi, I am looking for an WYSIWYG view. I will have a look at xdocdiff as an option. Word isn't really viable due to licencing.